# ListView Custom Control Template reset when adding view

Tags: wpf, listview, custom-controls

The control resets to the standard ListView in the designer when I declare a view in XAML.

```
        <my1:CustomControl1.View>
            <GridView></GridView>
        </my1:CustomControl1.View>
```

I tried doing the same thing in code. The CustomControl1.Template changes from having a TargetType of "CustomControl1" to the default ListView template after I set the view to a new  GridView().

The template itself doesn't seem to be the problem - it works if I use it as a local resource. If I can't get this working I could make a UserControl with a templated listview inside but for various reasons I'd like a CustomControl. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution here. You create your own GridView class and have it return the custom control as the default style key. You then use this instead of the standard gridview

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/056df061-0666-4fe2-9fa6-8a6440a23ff0/